# jQuery - change table cell color if clicked and clicked again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok, so I have the following simple code which changes the background color to red of a selected cell in a table. It works great.

CSS:

```
.fixture-table td.team.on {
    background-color: red;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
    // change the color to red on table when clicked
    $('td').click( function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('on');
    });
});
```

What I'm looking to do is when the cell is clicked, change to red. If the same cell is clicked again then change to yellow. Then if clicked again, change to no background color, so to have three states.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’d add a data attribute to save the current state. Then change the classes depending on this state.

http://jsfiddle.net/NhT92/

```
$('td').click(function () {
    var cell = $(this),
        state = cell.data('state') || 'first';

    switch (state) {
        case 'first':
            cell.addClass('red');
            cell.data('state', 'second');
            break;
        case 'second':
            cell.addClass('yellow');
            cell.data('state', 'third');
            break;
        case 'third':
            cell.removeClass('red yellow');
            cell.data('state', 'first');
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
});
```

CSS

```
.red {
    background-color: red;
}
.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Don’t forget to mark it as the correct answer if it fits your needs :)

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.redColor { background-color:red; }
.yellowColor { background-color:yellow; }
.noColor { background-color:#fff; }
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {

    $('td').click( function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('noColor')) {
          $(this).removeClass('noColor').addClass('redColor');
        }
        else if($(this).hasClass('redColor')){
          $(this).removeClass('redColor').addClass('yellowColor');
        }
        else{
          $(this).removeClass('yellowColor').addClass('noColor');
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: @LeBen Yeah it was a typo.!